# I want to get the records of multiple values for the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get values from the database based on two values of my own, the values must match the id of the database

```
id   contactid  flag        flag_type 
-----------------------------------
1    99         Volunteer   1 
2    99         Uploaded    2 
3    100        Via Import  3 
4    100        Volunteer   1  
5    100        Uploaded    2
```

So from here I would want to get the rows with the id's 1 and 2, and ignore the rest of the values. But say for example that the row with the id 2 does not exist the statement would not return any row.

I've tried the following statement, but it doesn't seem to work :

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE id IN (1) AND id IN (2);
```

Comment: Try in operator with comma-seperated ID values as `SELECT * FROM docs WHERE id IN (1,2);`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I need both values to exist not just one, so if one value doesn't exist the statement returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use OR

```
    SELECT * FROM docs 
    WHERE id IN (1) OR  id IN (2);
```

or

```
    SELECT * FROM docs 
    WHERE id = 1  
    OR  id = 2;
```

or if you need the records for contactid with both id (1,2) then

```
    select * from docs 
    inner join (
        select  contactid 
        from docs 
        where id IN (1, 2) 
        having count(distinct id ) = 2
    ) t on t.contactid = docs.contactid
```

Comment: I need both values to exist not just one, so if one value doesn't exist the statement returns nothing

Comment: @JordanPattinson What if contactid for id = 2 equals 98 ..?

Answer (score 0):

you need subquery

```
select id from table_name where contactid in (
select contactid
from table_nae
group by contactid
having count(*)=2
)
```

subquery will pick only those contactid whose count is two and in condition of main query will help to pick your desired id

Answer (score 0):

If you want the contacts with exactly those flags, you can do:

```
select contactid
from t
group by contactid
having sum(flag = 1) > 0 and         -- has 1
       sum(flag = 2) > 0 and         -- has 2
       sum(flag not in (1, 2)) = 0;  -- has nothing else
```

There are various ways to get the original rows -- using `in` or `exists` or `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select contactid
      from t
      group by contactid
      having sum(flag = 1) > 0 and         -- has 1
             sum(flag = 2) > 0 and         -- has 2
             sum(flag not in (1, 2)) = 0   -- has nothing else
     ) tt
     on t.contactid = tt.contactid;
```